# Vector of objects of derived classes with different templates

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Considering the base class below:

```
template <typename T>
class food {
public:
    T quantity;
};
```

Now deriving two classes with different template instances:

```
class cheese: public food<float> {
}
class chocolate: public food<int> {
}
```

In the main function, I need to create a list of 'food' instances

```
int main () {
    vector<food*> bucket;
}
```

Because I don't know what kind of food would be thrown into bucket. However, compiling this code would generate error:

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘*’ token
```

Thus, what can I do about this?

---

Now I need to define member functions for the derived classes:

```
class cheese: public food<float> {
    float get_q() {return quantity};
}
class chocolate: public food<int> {
    int get_q() {return quantity};
}
```

The problem is, the compiler would say class food has no member get_q if I call:

```
bucket.push_back(new cheese);
bucket.push_back(new chocolate);
bucket[0]->get_q();
```

in main, even if I change the Quantity interface like this

```
template <typename T>
class Quantity{
public:
    T quantity;
    virtual T get_q() = 0;
};
```

It seems that the compiler does need to see `get_q()` defined in `food`, but that's not possible if `food` is not a template, right?

Sorry I am a new C++ programmer, a lot of things are not clear for me...

Comment: The template arguments are part of the type, so it's not really possible. You might be able to solve it through [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html) though.

Comment: Yeah,boost::any is good option.

Comment: Thank you all for the solutions. I really need to write the code without Boost library. In @RSahu 's solution, it seems that I have to have all the member functions of the derived classes virtually defined in 'food' class, otherwise the compiler says the function is not a member of 'food' at compilation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `food<float>` and `food<int>` are different types, they cannot be used as if they were polymorphic.
- `food*` does not name a type, since an argument is required for the template (which is what the compiler is telling you)

Either you provide a common base to all `food<>` types (and you probably need that if the types are really related), or you will need some kind of type erasure wrappers, such as [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html).

---

**`boost::any` example :**

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

template <typename T>
class food {
public:
    T quantity;
};

class cheese: public food<float> {
};

class cholocate: public food<int> {
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::any> v;
    v.push_back(food<float>());
    v.push_back(food<int>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a base class `food` that is not a class template and make a class template that captures the quantity.

```
class food
{
};

template <typename T>
class Quantity{
public:
    T quantity;
};

class cheese: public food, public Quantity<float> {
};

class cholocate: public food, public Quantity<int> {
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<food*> v;
    v.push_back(new cheese);
    v.push_back(new cholocate);
}
```

**Update, in response comment by OP about the need to add**

You can add a `get_quantity()` function like:

```
class food
{
   public:
      virtual float get_quantity() const = 0;
};

class cheese: public food, public Quantity<float> {
   public:
      virtual float get_quantity() const
      {
         return this->quantity;
      }
};

class cholocate: public food, public Quantity<int> {
   public:
      virtual float get_quantity() const
      {
         return this->quantity; // Implicit conversion to float.
      }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Suppose that I add `float get_quantity()` to cheese and `int get_quantity()` to chocolate. And call them in main using v[0]->get_quantity. The compiler says that `class food doesn't have member get_quantity`. But I cannot add it to `food` class because the return value is overridden. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @xna, please elaborate. What do you want to add? To what do you want add?

Comment: I elaborate the question for more detail. Thank you very much.